# Symfony error - I don't know what it means

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and I am getting this error and I don't really know what it means.If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of the error
[image: Screen shot of the error]

Comment: What are you doing at that route? What kind of queries? Maybe it is something that is too big or taking too long that the mysql connection is closing.

Comment: I set it up so it's my root in MAMP so i can see my edits. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql settings in the file /app/config/parameters.yml

Personnaly I doubt your DB port is '8888'.

Try to access the url http:///localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/check.php and check if it's all green.

Hope it may helps you.

Comment: My DB port is 8889 i tried with that but it dosent work. I am using MAMP does it make a difference ?

Comment: If you execute the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'`, what is the result?